# How to get the file name and id3 tags of an mp3 file in a Windows 8 metro app using javascript?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

All I wanna do is list the files from the music library. I wanna list the path of the file, the author and the title. The Windows 8 Javascript API offers neat asynchronous  functions. My problem is that I cannot pass a variable to the function, so  I cannot identify the file inside the callback function. Here's what I have so far:

```
var musicLibrary = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.musicLibrary;
musicLibrary.getFilesAsync().then(function (resultLibrary) {
 for (var i = 0; i < resultLibrary.length; i++) {
  var path = resultLibrary[i].path;
  resultLibrary[i].properties.getMusicPropertiesAsync().then(function (musicProperties) {
  $("#list").append('<li>'+ musicProperties.artist + ', ' + musicProperties.title + '</li>');
}
});
```

As you can see, I can retrieve every information, I just can't put them together to one list item. Can anyone tell me how this is done? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/573218) in javascript:

```
var musicLibrary = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.musicLibrary;
musicLibrary.getFilesAsync().then(function (resultLibrary) {

    for (var i = 0; i < resultLibrary.length; i++) {
    (function(song){
        var path = song.path;
        song.properties.getMusicPropertiesAsync().done(function (musicProperties) {
            $("#list").append('<li>' + song.path + musicProperties.artist + ', ' + musicProperties.title + '</li>');
        })
    })(resultLibrary[i]);
    }
});
```

Comment: It's working, thanks! I'm gonna look into the closure stuff now.